# Android: the print quality is bad

Tags: printing

we have a problem with Android printing. The print qualitity is bad.

- The font has podium on the edge
- "Gaps" in the font inside
- broken lines

**We have the following printers:**

- Samsung Xpress M2026W
- Brother HL-L2350DW

The connection is made via WLAN.

**We tried the following variant:**

- Samsung & Brother Print Service:

  - via external Apps (Adobe Reader)
  - our own native App (printerHelper, printManager, ...)
- Samsung Mobile Print App:

  - Direct call and print of a PDF / image (JPEG / PNG)
  - Call through our app with explicit intent
- Samsung Cloud Print
- Brother Mobile Print App:

  - Direct call and print of a PDF / image (JPEG / PNG)

The only variant with good print is printing with a desktop PC (Windows 10, Ubuntu 14.04 and 18.04)

So there is generally no Problem with the printers.

It was tested on Android 6, 7, 8 & 9 and many tablets and smartphones (LG, Lenovo, Nexus, Pixel and Huawei)

To exclude images and fonts that could cause problems, we also tested third-party PDFs and docx with Arial.

Are there solutions to that? Be it settings (Android, manufacturer App or printer) or programmatic solutions? We would be so far, the printer directly address, if this is possible?! Also, we could imagine hiring consulting firms, if anybody knows any on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when printing from android to my Brother HL-2340D.
My prints included a barcode which couldn't even be scanned when printed from my android-device.
What I did to fix it was downloading Brother [Print Service Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brother.printservice)
With this installed you get a new option in the list of printers. With this one there's a new button in the print-settings, "MORE OPTIONS" pressing this takes you to a new with 2 more settings, 1 being Quality. The options there are "Normal", "Fine", "Best" with the default being "Fine". This prints in about the same quality as without the plugin. Maybe a tad better. "Best" prints in about the same quality as the default settings on my pc, which is 600 DPI.

Oh, and the "Normal" option is anything but normal.